# Exception handling: Try - catch statements in Java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am trying to use a try catch statement after importing a file and keep getting and error under the catch(FileNOtFoundException e) It is telling my the exception is never thrown from the try statement body and to remove it from the body.

```
//import scanner needed for input dialog
import java.util.Scanner;  
import java.io.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;


    public class Lab5{
        public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException{
            NumberFormat fmtCurr = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Get the filename
                String fileName = null;
                File inputFile = new File(fileName);
                Scanner file = new Scanner(inputFile);
                boolean invalid;
            do{
                System.out.print("Data file of prior internet usage: ")
                try{
                    double avg;
                    double paid;
                    double total;
                    System.out.println("Usage history:");
                    while (file.hasNextLine()){
                        avg = file.nextDouble();
                        paid = file.nextDouble();
                        total = file.nextDouble();          
                        System.out.println( "Average Hours Used:" + avg);
                        System.out.println( "Average Paid:" + fmtCurr.format(paid));
                        System.out.println( "Total Paid:" + fmtCurr.format(total));
                    }
                    invalid = false;
                }

            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                System.out.print("file does not exist");
                invalid = true;
                }
            }

            while(invalid = true);



    }
}
```

Comment: The thing that can throw a `FileNotFoundException` is `new Scanner(inputFile)`.

Comment: Which line inside your try statement do you think could throw a `FileNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 0):

The `try` block has to *contain* the line that could throw the exception which in this case is the `Scanner file = new Scanner(inputFile);` line. If you move that line inside the `try` block, then it will catch the exception if it is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

> It is telling my the exception is never thrown from the try statement body...

Yes, it's telling you the exact problem. `java.io.FileNotFoundException` is not thrown by any lines of code within your `try` block.

Based on what your code is doing, it seems like you wanted to catch `java.util.InputMismatchException` instead.

```
            catch (InputMismatchException e) // not FileNotFoundException
            {
                System.out.print("Invalid double input");
                invalid = true;
            }
```